# Can I ask for a list of papers of interest to programmers (and not only CS theorists)?

Tags: discussion, list-questions

I'm thinking of asking a question for papers (e.g. from IEEE or ACM) that are of interest to programmers.

There's similar question at [Theoretical Computer Science](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1168/what-papers-should-everyone-read) that has some great answers, but there's a lot of theory there and I'm more interested in less theoretical ones with more interest to programmers and engineers day-to-day at the code-face.

This would result in a list, and should be one answer per paper, with a summary of why we should read this paper. I hope to find some classic and influential papers of interest to the community.

- Would this be allowed?
- Should it be community wiki?
- What tags to you recommend?
- If not here on Programmers.SE, how about another site?
- What's the general Programmers.SE policy on list-generating questions?

This similar question was [closed](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/870/if-you-could-only-have-one-programming-related-book-on-your-bookshelf-what-would) as not constructive but this similar question is [open](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/966/what-non-programming-books-should-a-programmer-read-to-help-develop-programming-t).

Comment: The question you point to that remains open is from the early days of Programmers when rules were different. It likely slipped through the cracks and we're reviewing it to see if it deserves to stay open.

Comment: Definitely slipped through the cracks. I locked both and threw up the historical significance notice. Beyond Walter's answer, there's [Are “I'm looking for X” questions on topic?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/1624/are-im-looking-for-x-questions-on-topic) which goes into more detail.

Answer (score 2):

If you check the FAQ, you'll see that questions that result in lists for answers are generally considered not constructive, as they usually don't meet the 6 guidelines to asking questions.

Where most list questions fail is in the ability to meet these:

- inspire answers that explain “why” and “how”
- tend to have long, not short, answers
- invite sharing experiences over opinions

If you can come up with a way to ask your question to satsify these, it would stand a good chance at remaining open.